# Android - Square ImageButton in GridLayout

Tags: android

I am new in  Android so please be patient :)

In my main screen/ main activity i want to have grid 2 x N, so I want to have two columns and N rows. The item in the grid is ImageButton.

Everything is working fine, when the img in ImageButtons is ic_launcher -> then the items in grid are fine. But when I put my graphic (500x500px) the "tiles" are bigger than screen and I don't know how to "scale" this img to fit tiles, so they can have the same size as when they have ic_launcher.

Here is code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>      

</GridLayout>
```

Here is screen when everything is fine:

[image]

What can i do to scale my img to fit this size?

Important thing: My img is in square proportion so i want to scale this img to square size.

EDIT: when I use my img it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I bet you are not using the correct `android:scaleType`. Why don't you show us how it looks like with your own picture ?

Comment: why you are using two ImageButton inside gridLayout?, it don't make sense.

Comment: @JonZarate i made update, i tested all scaleType

Comment: @NandanKumarSingh why don't make sense? What should i do?

Comment: use gridView instead of grid layout or RecyclerView . and fix height if layout. in gridView layout place ImageView and set scaleType to centerCrop to fill image to ImageView.

Comment: Can you know add a picture of what you want to achieve  + your full XML ?

Comment: I had the same problem, no solution. I changed the GridLayout in ConstraintLayout and all is become perfect. Android studio converts it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my try..

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Integer> integerRes = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);
        integerRes.add(R.drawable.bbent);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());


    }

    class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return integerRes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ImageView imageView=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,440));
            // for better result in various devices calculate width at runtime and measure height accordingly

            imageView.setImageResource(integerRes.get(i));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            return imageView;
        }
    }

}
```

grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: wow, I think this is what i need. When i go back to home I will test it and give You "accept". Thanks!

Comment: everything is fine, but what should I do to set height the same as width? Instead of typing "440"

Comment: just take screen width at runtime and set it there by divide by 2

Comment: I have did it exactly as You wrote, everything works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a tweak for the same problem I faced ::

Wrap the ImageButton by a LinearLayout as::

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:gravity="center">

       <ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:gravity="center">

       <ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout
```

Apply the margins and paddings to the ImageButton or LinearLayout as required. This is just concept, make things work your way.

Comment: ok, it can works, but i want to have GridLayout, not Linear. I will check the other solution if it will be bad I will try Yours solution. Thanks for help