# Enforce fixed component size in GridLayout

Tags: android, imageview, grid-layout

I have a 4*4 grid of ImageViews arranged in a GridLayout.
[image: Design View]

When I update the ImageViews, the scale of all items in the grid changes in proportion to the image provided, shown here with Android icons as base ImageViews, and 2 brown updated ImageViews.

[image: Scaling Relative To Updates]

This goes to the extreme when I attempt to update a significant amount of the ImageViews, and everything is shifted offscreen

[image: Shift offscreen]

Every ImageView is initialized the same way (except for row-column location)

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/tileImg00"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor" />
```

How can I fix the size of the ImageViews? I want to set the image, scale it so that it fits within the bounds of the ImageView as displayed in the design blueprint, and make sure that the image does not allow the ImageView to break the original orientation of the grid.

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mrybak834.a2048.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="195dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileImg33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_descriptor"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318761/android-square-imagebutton-in-gridlayout/42319279#42319279

Comment: I also faced this problem recently. You are not recycling your gridview properly. Show your gridview adapter and xml codes.

Comment: @tahsinRupam I am not using a gridView, but a gridLayout. Nothing is being done at runtime and I am not using an adapter. Would your alternative be a better solution?

Comment: then you can try to use fixed height and width to your imageview

Comment: Setting the maximum and minimum widths/heights did not change anything. I am looking for the preferred way to implement a feature like this.

Comment: can you provide your xml code please ? (With lesser images)

Comment: You're not using any scrollView, If images exeed screen what does happen ? Does that cause blank screen ?

Comment: If an image exceeds the screen, everything else is resized. However if a certain amount of images cause too many resizes (in my case 6 images), then everything goes very var in a certain direction, mostly offscreen.

Comment: yeah, then i recommend you to use gridview instead of gridlayout. GridLayout can be used for small amount of images.